# What's wrong with my average function? in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, function, average, mean

I am trying to write a function that when i call it returns the average (mean)  of an array of numbers. Here's what I have so far but right now am clueless on why this won't work. Any advice?

```
func average(Array arr: [Int]) -> Int{
    var average = 0
    var counter = 0
    for i in arr{

        average = arr[i] + average
        counter = counter + 1
        if(counter == arr.count){
            var average = (average / arr.count)
        }
    }
    return average
}
```

Comment: What does `i` represent?

Comment: `for i in arr` and then `arr[i]` look veeeery fishy. And overall that looks like the longest and most complicated way ever to calculate the average.

Comment: you also have 2 separate variables called `average`

Comment: It will also help to name your variables better. Your first of two "average" variables should be named "sum" since it is the running total, not the average.

Comment: Another error: average of an `Int` array may not be an `Int`. For example `average([1,2]) == 1.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

- `for i in arr` enumerates the array *elements,* not the array indices.
  Therefore `i` and not `arr[i]` is what you want to add to the 
  running sum (and `arr[i]` may crash with an index-out-of-range exception).
- `var average = (average / arr.count)` defines a local variable
  within the scope of the if-block, which hides the outer variable with the same name. In other words, that assignment does not modify the
  `average` variable which is ultimately returned from the function.

Fixing these two issues you get

```
func average(arr: [Int]) -> Int{
    var average = 0
    var counter = 0
    for elem in arr {
        average = elem  + average
        counter = counter + 1
        if(counter == arr.count){
            average = (average / arr.count)
        }
    }
    return average
}
```

which works (but of course truncates the result to an integer
due to the used integer division):

```
print(average(arr: [1, 2, 4])) // 2
```

The function can be simplified to

```
func average(arr: [Int]) -> Int{
    var sum = 0
    for elem in arr {
        sum += elem
    }
    return sum / arr.count
}
```

and further to

```
func average(arr: [Int]) -> Int{
    return arr.reduce(0, +) / arr.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a counter in a for each loop. 
also you cannot declare your average variable twice just initialize it once in the beginning. 
try

```
func average(Array arr: [Int]) -> Int{
    var avg = 0
    var sum = 0
    for i in arr{

        sum = i + sum

    }
    avg = sum / arr.count
    return avg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't want the mean of integers because it's not the true mean.

ex: the mean of [2,3] would spit out 2 with integers

also you can simplify your code with a reduce function.

```
var arr: [Double] = [...]
if arr.count > 0 {
  arr.reduce(0, +)/Double(arr.count)
}
```

as far as your function goes, this should work

```
func average(_ arr: [Double]) -> Double {
  if arr.count == 0 { return 0 }
  var average = 0.0
  for i in arr {
    average += i
  }
  return average/Double(arr.count)
}
```